# Can I make a YouTube video autoplay in HTML?

Tags: html

I have this code that is just a funny troll video, but I don't know if you are able to make a video autoplay or if it needs to be manually clicked on by the user.

```
<div id="banner">
        <h2><strong>Welcome To My Portfolio!</strong>
        <br /> My Name is <span style="color: red">John</span>, and  I am excited 
        to meet you!</h2>
        <p>Does this statement make you want to click the big shiny button?</p>
        <a href="https://youtu.be/eBGIQ7ZuuiU?t=1" target="_blank" 
        class="button large icon solid fa-check-circle">Yes it does</a>
</div>
```

I tried just adding an autoplay feature to the end of the  tag, as well as trying it in other spots but I am just not quite sure.

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -1):

```
<video autoplay>
  <source src="https://youtu.be/eBGIQ7ZuuiU?t=1" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Can you show me how I would incorporate that into the bit of code? I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post